# Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy

Пробую сделать пуш проекта на гит и получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit  Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Есть идеи как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Необходимо в файл gradle.properties добавить вот такую строку

org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home

Только путь к jdk необходимо смотреть конкретно на вашей машине